# Can't run program after compilation with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

So, i am trying to run a program i wrote in C, in my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (in a virtual machine)

it compiles without a problem, the make command runs smoothly but the program itself doesn't run

shell$ ./prot

This gives me the following error:

```
bash: ./prot: Permission Denied
```

These are the permissions on the file:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root sdcard-rw 8609 Mar 20 16:23 prot
```

What could this be, and how can i overcome this little problem?

PS.: I'm using Ubuntu, this program compiles and runs well on my Mac.

EDIT: See the answer of teppic, it solved my problem.

Comment: You need the execute `x` permission.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you dont have X permission for anyone to execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very likely that your sdcard is mounted with `noexec`, which prevents you from executing any files on it. If you look in `/etc/fstab`, and there's an entry for the sdcard, take out this option. It's also normally possible to remount with the `exec` option with `mount -o remount,exec`.

Otherwise, you may be able to copy it somewhere where executables are allowed (e.g. `/tmp`).

Comment: And you were right! Thank you very much to you and the others that tried to help me!

Answer (score 1):

You have to have permission for execution, i. e. the `x` bit set. Try

```
chmod +x prot
```

to fix it.

Comment: Tried that, the permissions didn't change, still the same error.
Tried that command and also with sudo before it. Nothing.

Comment: @Souza Then you're missing something else. Are you sure you're `chmod`ding the same file you're trying to run?

Comment: I think you need to chown and *then* chmod. I've also had chmod refuse the +x parameter but accept numerical ones like 777 on some systems.

Comment: seems the problem was that i didn't have the rights to change permissions at all inside the SD card, remounted with exec and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need admin permission to change it, try:

$> sudo chmod 777 prot